# Use named r color in rgb() so I can add alpha value

Tags: r, colors

To make it easier to test colors in a complex plot, I'd like to use named colors but specify alpha.  My first thought was to use `col2rgb()`.  Something like this

```
rgb( col2rgb( "red" ), alpha=125, maxColorValue=255 )
```

But the output of col2rgb() is a matrix.  I've tried transposing it, converting it to character, etc., but can't get it in a form that `rgb()` can use.  Which is strange, since it's called `col2rgb`.

The situation is more complex than this, and I have to specify the alpha when giving the color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `t`ranspose to create a 3 column `matrix` as the `col2rgb` is a single column `matrix` with row.names i.e.

```
col2rgb( "red" )
#       [,1]
#red    255
#green    0
#blue     0
t(col2rgb( "red" ))
#     red green blue
#[1,] 255     0    0
```

and according to `?rgb`

> The colors may be specified by passing a matrix or data frame as argument red, and leaving blue and green missing. In this case the first three columns of red are taken to be the red, green and blue values.

So, we can use a 3 column `matrix`

```
rgb(t(col2rgb( "red" )), alpha=125, maxColorValue=255 )
#[1] "#FF00007D"
```

Or as a `data.frame`

```
rgb(as.data.frame(t(col2rgb( "red" ))), alpha=125, maxColorValue=255 )
#[1] "#FF00007D"
```

which is the same as

```
rgb(red = 255, green = 0, blue = 0, alpha=125, maxColorValue=255 )
#[1] "#FF00007D"
```

Comment: Thanks!  I swear I tried that but must have fouled it up somehow.  Also, not having read ?rgb well enough, I had no reason to think it would really work.